# Can't get list of tuples to convert to list of strings correctly

Tags: python, mysql, tuples

I use the following code to get a certain list of tuples (if I'm not mistaken) from MySQL into python. I use the `''.join()` function to convert the tuples into strings, but it leaves out the first part e.g. the `print(match_tuples)` returns `[('Dortmund VS Hoffenheim',), ('Arminia VS Frankfurt',),` (this is only a part of the list). But in the second `mycursor.execute()` it starts by only inputting `VS Hoffenheim`, which it will obviously not find and thus throw an error.

How can I get it to return a list of strings (which are all complete)?

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT matchup FROM bundesliga")

matches_tuples = list(mycursor.fetchall())
print(matches_tuples)
matches = [' '.join(i) for i in matches_tuples]

for match in matches:
    mycursor.execute("SELECT MAX(Home) FROM eredivisie WHERE matchup = " + match)
    print(match)
    for x in mycursor:
        print(x)
```

Comment: please use `mycursor.execute("SELECT MAX(Home) FROM eredivisie WHERE matchup = (?); " , (match,))`

Comment: not sure about your error, can you `print(match)`, if `eredivisie` does not have the exact name you can try with `LIKE` `mycursor.execute("SELECT MAX(Home) FROM eredivisie WHERE matchup LIKE %(?)%; " , (match,))`